# Efficiency index bar chart

Tags: excel

From data:

```
     Efficiency
```

ITV Drama   98
C4 Movies   101
More 4 Movies   92
E4 Movies   106
Film4           100

How to get the output as below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your chart data, insert another row that is computed as the score - 100.

[image]

Select this row of data, and then do Insert | Chart, Column Chart:

[image]

From there it is a simple matter of making the formatting adjustments (remove the legend, add a title, set the axis scale & gridline display properties, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did this though. Just wanted to know how would we reference it by 100.

Comment: What do you mean "reference it by 100"?

Answer (score 1):

I have interpreted the question as being almost entirely about formatting and aimed for:

[image: SO17935424 example]

This uses some workarounds:

1. Since not all values under 100 are coloured the same I see no 'rule' to follow so have merely chosen a light blue for the entire series and then selected ITV Drama to change its colour.
2. The Film4 value at 100 disappears behind the grid line, so I have adjusted this to 101 in the source.

For charting I found it easier to plot only the values (98, 101, 92, 106, 101.0) (from separate adjacent cells - Text to Columns if necessary) and then add the horizontal axis labels separately, as an axis title, with enough spaces to suit.

Obviously the y-axis is set Fixed Minimum: 50, Maximum: 150, Major Unit: 10, Major tick mark type: Outside and Horizontal axis crosses: Axis value: 100. Number format General. Other settings default.